# How to vectorize a pandas datetime column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, iteration, vectorization

I'm trying to use vectorization to take a pandas dataframe column and change all of the days for a particular month to one day, however, it seems like the column is still being interpreted as a series, rather than being iterated over. Can anyone help with what I'm doing wrong?

The column I want to change is ['Date_Time']. For example, if an entry is '2019-05-11 09:00:00', I want to change it to '2019-05-15 09:00:00'.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from random import random

# Create a mini-dataframe to test on
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['WindowID', 'Date_Time', 'Occlusion'])
dy = 11
for i in range(6):
    x = i+1
    hr = 9
    while hr < 18:
        z = random()
        y = datetime(year=2019, month=5, day=dy, hour=hr, minute=00, second=00)
        df = df.append({'WindowID': x, 'Date_Time': y, 'Occlusion': z}, ignore_index=True)
        hr += 2
    dy += 1

# Create a function for normalizing the day of the month
def normmonth(dt):
    print(dt.month)
    if dt.month == 5:
        rpday = 15
    elif dt.month == 10:
        rpday = 30
    dt2 = dt.replace(day=rpday)
    return dt2

df['Date_Time2'] = normmonth(df['Date_Time'])
```

This is the error: "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'month'".

Also  I found this to be a really helpful article about [iterating over pandas dataframes](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6)

Comment: `df['Date_Time2'] = df['Date_Time'].apply(normmonth)`

Comment: Thank you @CainãMaxCouto-Silva. This works, although I was hoping to learn how to do it without using the apply method since from what I've read the best way is to use pure vectorization. That said, this definitely gets me what I need.